# Issues with align

Tags: align, split, resize

I tried applying align on this long equation

```
(*Packages*)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{4.5}}
\newcommand{\Vast}{\bBigg@{5}}
\makeatother
(*Packages Ends*)

\title{Math Stack Question}
\author{bharathk98}
\date{May 2020}

(*Document Begin*)
\begin{document}

\maketitle

(*Equation Begins*)
\begin{align}
& \lambda^{*}_{A}(S)=\\
&\inf\left\{\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\ell(I_{k,\epsilon})
\bigl[1{-}\mu(A)(1{-}\mu(S\cap I_{k,\epsilon}))\bigr]\text{sign}(|A|)}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})
\bigl[1{-}\mu(A)(1{-}\mu(A\cap J_{k,\epsilon}))\bigr]}: S\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m} I_{k,\epsilon},\\ 
& A\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n} J_{k,\epsilon}, \left|\lambda^{*}(S)-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\ell(I_{k,\epsilon})\right|\le \epsilon, \left|\lambda^{*}(A)-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})\right|\le \epsilon, \\ 
& 1\le m \le \max\left\{|S|,1\right\}, 1 \le n \le \max\left\{|A|,1\right\}; P = S\cap I_{k,\epsilon}, P= A\cap J_{k,\epsilon} \ \text{or} \\ 
& P= A; \mu(P)=\inf\left\{\text{sign}\left(\bigcup\limits_{s=1}^{t}G_s\right): P\subseteq \bigcup\limits_{s=1}^{t} G_s\right\}, 1 \le t \le \max\left\{|P|,1\right\} \right\}
\end{align}
(*Equation Ends*)

\end{document}
```

But it returns error signs. It says I have to use `\left.` and `\right.` but I'm not sure how to apply them.

Comment: Unrelated the use of `\text` is wrong here.

Comment: FOr start remove all `(*Packages Ends*)` etc,  from your document example. Your code for `align` has error `! Extra }, or forgoten \right`.

Comment: @Zarko I didn’t include my entire document because it is much longer.

Comment: you should post a document that people can use adding that text means the document as posted just  gives errors

Comment: also this is a duplicate of your earlier question  I think

Comment: I didn't ask you to include whole document :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} in recent article is default
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb} % mathtoola define \shortintertext 
                                % and load amsmath package
                                % amssymb load amsfonts too
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}           % had to be loaded last
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{4.5}}
\newcommand{\Vast}{\bBigg@{5}}
\makeatother

\title{Math Stack Question}
\author{bharathk98}
\date{May 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

    \begin{align}
\lambda^{*}_{A}(S)
    & = \inf\left\{\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\ell(I_{k,\epsilon})
\bigl[1{-}\mu(A)(1{-}\mu(S\cap I_{k,\epsilon}))\bigr] \sign(|A|)}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})
\bigl[1{-}\mu(A)(1{-}\mu(A\cap J_{k,\epsilon}))\bigr]}: S\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m} I_{k,\epsilon}\right.,\\
%
A   & \subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n} J_{k,\epsilon}, \left|\lambda^{*}(S)-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\ell(I_{k,\epsilon})\right|\le \epsilon, \left|\lambda^{*}(A)-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})\right|\le \epsilon, \\
    & 1\le m \le \max\left\{|S|,1\right\}, 1 \le n \le \max\left\{|A|,1\right\}; P = S\cap I_{k,\epsilon}, P= A\cap J_{k,\epsilon} 
%
\shortintertext{or}
%
P   & = A; \mu(P)=\inf\left\{\text{sign}\left(\bigcup\limits_{s=1}^{t}G_s\right): P\subseteq \bigcup\limits_{s=1}^{t} G_s\right\}, 1 \le t \le \max\left\{|P|,1\right\}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, your equation is to wide that be nicely fit in the default `article` page layout. Therefore I add the package `geometry, which increase` textwidth`.

**Edit:**
Or you you maybe like to have:

[image]

where is is instead `\right.` after the frst equation used `\right\}`.